# $E|A_1|<\infty$ and i.o events for $\left\{A_n\right\}$ are iid

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Given $\left\{A_n\right\}$ are i.i.d. Show that $E(|A_1|)< \infty$ $\iff \ P\left\{|A_n| > n \ \ \text{i.o}\right\} = 0$.

**My attempt:** **($\Rightarrow$)** Assume $E(|A_1|)< \infty$. Since $\left\{A_n\right\}$ are i.i.d, by the Strong Law of Large Number, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |A_i|\rightarrow E(|A_1|)$ almost surely. This is equivalent to $\forall\  \epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(\cup_{k\geq n}|(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k} |A_i|)-E(|A_1|)|\geq \epsilon)= 0$. This implies for sufficiently large $k$, $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k} |A_i| - E(|A_1|)\ <\ \epsilon$. Since we don't know whether $E(|A_1|) > 1$ or not, we cannot choose $\epsilon = 1-E(|A_1|)$ to get $|A_k|$ bounded above by $k$. Could someone please help with this part?

**($\Leftarrow$)** If $P\left\{|A_n| > n \ \ \text{i.o}\right\} = 0$, this implies for sufficiently large $k$, $k$ is fixed, $|A_k|< k$. This implies $E(|A_k|) = E(|A_1|) < E(k) = k < \infty$ (the first equality is due to $\left\{A_n\right\}$ are iid).

**My question:** Could someone help complete my "solution" above for the forward direction? If I'm on the wrong track, please help point that out to me.

Comment: Well, this might seem silly, but can you tell me what _**i.o.**_ means?

Comment: @Qwerty: i.o = infinitely often. And no, it's not silly.

Comment: Well, can you be kind enough to specify the defnition of _**i.o.**_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forward part is an easy consequence of Borel-Cantelli'e lemma. First of all see that:
$$
\mathbb E(|A_1|)\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|A_1|>n).
$$
Using i.i.d. assumption:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|A_1|>n)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|A_n|>n).
$$
So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|A_n|>n)<\infty$ and therefore from Borel-Cantelli's lemma:
$$
\mathbb P(|A_n|>n , \rm{ i.o. })=0.
$$

Comment: thank you for your help. I don't think we have the coefficient $n$ in the first inequality? Otherwise, great proof (I should have thought of that:P). Btw, could you help verify if my solution for the reverse direction is correct?

Comment: Your reverse direction seems fine to me. I also think that the coefficient $n$ should be there. That's why something stronger can be proved using bounded first moment.

Comment: The correct inequality is: for any $X\geq 0$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X > k)\leq E(X)\leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X > k)$

Comment: Yes you are right. I mixed it up with something else.